# Wordpress show content based on body class

Tags: wordpress

I was using the Wordpress is_category(); function to show my sidebars on just category pages, but for some reason whenever I add a certain category to the function, the sidebar starts to show on the homepage as well. I'm trying to find an alternate method. All of the category pages have a body class of catPage, is there a way to say if the body has a class of catPage, then show this content?

Comment: "All of the category pages have a body class of catPage, is there a way to say if the body has a class of catPage, then show this content?"
Use jQuery `$('body').hasClass('catPage')`

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't think of mixing in jQuery. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) function (without any arguments) should return `true` only on category list pages and so that *should* work.

You could make use of the `is_archive()` function which is true for every page displaying categories and more, [from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Any_Archive_Page):

> When any type of Archive page is being displayed. Category, Tag,
>   Author and Date based pages are all types of Archives.

Comment: That still shows the sidebar on the homepage. I know they both should work, I'm not sure why the site seems to think the home page is also an archive/category page. I used is_category() both without arguments, and with an array of arguments listing each category ID separately, and it worked fine with the array until I listed one particular category, so it seems to think the homepage is a specific category page.